# Vertical scroll bar using d3.js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This question is continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203793/vertical-scroll-bar-using-brush-d3-v4) . As i have managed to scroll the content using clip and brush api using d3.js .
But i have an issue with scaling with data and what i expected is behavior of the css scroll bar.

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/fab55o3y/1/)

```
var brush = d3.brushY().extent([[0, 0], [10, 150]]).on("start brush end", brushmoved);
```

As my scroll area will be 150 px.

Comment: Please provide a copy of your code or a working example as a Stackoverflow snippet

Comment: Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/fab55o3y/1/)

Comment: Including a fiddle doesn't make it a good question for StackOverflow. If anyone comes to this question later they can't see what the problem is, and if the fiddle is ever removed/JSFiddle goes down then this question is useless. It's the equivalent of a `link only answer`